# Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$

Tags: limits

Calculate

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle \frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$$

I have messed around with this task for quite a while now, but I haven't succeeded to find the solution yet.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: I suppose that $x$ is $n$ and that $n^n-1$ is $n^{n-1}$. Is this a correct assumption ? If it is, please edit. Thanks.

Comment: It is constant as there is no x in the expression

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My fault! ^^

Comment: If I was given a dime for each typo I have done i my life, I should a billionaire ! So, don't worry (too much). Cheers

Comment: Observation:  $$\dfrac{(r+1)^r}{r^{r-1}}=r\left(1+\dfrac1r\right)^r$$

Now $2<\left(1+\dfrac1r\right)^r<3$

So, for the numerator$(N),$  $$2\sum_{r=}^nr<N<3\sum_{r=}^nr$$

Comment: Does that mean $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle \frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2} = \infty$ ? :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: lofty words.

Comment: It seems that the limit will be $\frac{e}{2}$ by some numerical approximation.

Comment: @Hetebrij. Could you describe ? I got the same but using a quite tricky way which, I am sure, is too complex. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We want to compute:
$$ \color{red}{L}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k.$$
The sequence given by $a_k=\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k $ is converging to $e$, hence
$$ b_k = \frac{k a_k + (k-1) a_{k-1} + \ldots + 2 a_2 + a_1}{k+(k-1)+\ldots+2+1} $$
is converging to $e$, too, by [Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean). Since $k+(k-1)+\ldots+1 = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, it follows that:
$$ L = \color{red}{\frac{e}{2}}.$$

Comment: This is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Combining $$\frac{1}{1-1/n}>1+\frac1n \ \ \ n>1 $$ with the fact that for all positive $n$ we have $$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<e<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}, $$ and after rewriting your sequence $a_n$ as $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k(1+1/k)^k$, we find the general term $s_k$ of the sum satisfies $$k\left(e-\frac ek\right)<s_k<ke$$. Thus $$\frac{e}{2} \leftarrow \frac{e}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{n^2} - \frac{e}{n} =\frac{e}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)<a_n< \frac{e}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac e2 \frac{n(n+1)}{n^2} \to \frac e2,$$ and by the squeeze theorem we conclude $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\displaystyle\frac e2$.