# Find the following limit with a sum

Tags: limits, summation

I am trying to solve the following limit, which includes a sum:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{1}{n^2}(2+\frac{3^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}})]$

So far, the only thing I have been able to do is to bound the limit between 0 and e:

- If $(2+\frac{3^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}) = 0 \to \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=0$
- If $(\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}) = n \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}} \to \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n^2}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e $

$0 < (2+\frac{3^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}) < (\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}) \to\\
 0 < \lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{1}{n^2}(2+\frac{3^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}})] < e$

This is fine, but I would like to know if a closer bound or an exact limit could be found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how they found this answer, but I typed the limit into Wolfram Alpha, and [they said the answer was $0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=the+limit+as+n+approaches+infinity+of+1%2Fn%5E2*(sum+from+i%3D1+to+n+of+(i%2B1)%5Ei%2Fi%5E(i-1))).

Comment: where did the factor $\frac{1}{n^2}$ go when you calculated the bounds?

Comment: The factor is used when calculating the limits itself.

Comment: See also: [Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607951) and [Evaluate the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{64}{9}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n-1}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025640).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression equals

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+1)^k/k^{k-1}}{n^2}.$$

Stolz-Cesaro says we should look at

$$\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}/(n+1)^n}{(n+1)^2 - n^2}=\frac{(1+1/(n+1))^n(n+2)}{2n+2}.$$

The last expresion $\to \frac{e}{2}.$ So by S-C, the limit is $e/2.$

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thanks!