# Evaluate the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{64}{9}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n-1}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{64}{9}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n-1}}\right)$$

---

My try:

The limit can be written as follows:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k-1}}\right)$$

Evaluate the following series:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k-1}}$

$\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k-1}}=k\cdot\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k}}=k\cdot\left(1+\frac{k+1}{k}-1\right)^k=k\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$

Then:

$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k-1}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}k\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=e\cdot\infty\neq0 \Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k-1}}$ diverges.

Therefore:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{64}{9}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n-1}}\right)=0\cdot\infty$$

What to do next?

Comment: You do not need to calculate the series. Also it is not valid to do so first. Try other things. Maybe **Cesaro-Stolz** theorem.

Comment: See also: [Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607951)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have that by Stolz-Cesaro

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k+1)^{k}}{k^{k-1}}}{n^2}$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n}}}{(n+1)^2-n^2}=\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)(n+1)^{n}}=\frac{n+2}{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n} \to \frac e 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{(k+1)^k}{k^{k-1}} = k \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$$
and
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k = \exp\left(k \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right) = \exp\left(1 + O(1/k)\right) = e + O(1/k)$$
Now, what can you say about $$\sum_{k=1}^n k (e + O(1/k))$$
?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user [xbh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/514490/xbh) for the hint:

Using the [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) theorem, we have:

$a_n=\frac{2}{1}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{64}{9}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n-1}}$

$b_n=n^2$

Two monotone and increasing sequences.

Apply the theorem to get:

$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}}{2n+1}=\frac{(n+2)(n+2)^{n}}{(2n+1)(n+1)^n}=\frac{n+2}{2n+1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{n+2}{n+1}-1\right)^n=\frac{n+2}{2n+1}\cdot\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right]^{\frac{1}{n+1}n}$

Then:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{9}{2}+\frac{64}{9}+\cdots+\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n-1}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+2}{2n+1}\cdot\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right]^{\frac{1}{n+1}n}=\frac{e}{2}$

Comment: Note that form here we don't need the extra exponent indeed we have simply $$=\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \to \frac e 2$$