# Limit $\frac{\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to determine the limit of the following sequence

$$x_n=\frac{\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$$

It is clear that the sequence $x_n$ is a sequence of the form $z_n=\frac{u_n}{v_n}$, with this try to apply Stolz's criterion by finding the limit of
$$\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{v_{n+1}-v_n}$$

However, I was not able to reach the specific limit. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Both [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B3%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%5E3%7D%7B3%5E2%7D%2B...%2B%5Cfrac%7B(n%2B1)%5En%7D%7Bn%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%24&p=1) and [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B3%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%5E3%7D%7B3%5E2%7D%2B...%2B%5Cfrac%7B%28n%2B1%29%5En%7D%7Bn%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%7D%24) return this post:  ...

Comment: ... [Calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{1}+\frac{3^2}{2}+\frac{4^3}{3^2}+...+\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607951). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying Stolz-Cesàro we get

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k+1)^k}{k^{k-1}}}{n^2}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2-(n-1)^2}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\frac{n+1}{n})^{n}}{2-1/n} = e/2
$$

Answer (score 0):

This directly follows from [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k+1)^k}{k^{k-1}}}{n^2}\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}}{n^2-(n-1)^2}\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}}{2-\frac 1n}\\
=&\frac e2
\end{align*}

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? Anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: May be the downvote is because your answer and mine are the same, but mine come out a few minutes before yours, so yours is redundant. (I didn't downvote)

Answer (score -1):

we have :
$$\frac{(n + 1)^n}{n^{n - 1}} = \frac{n^n}{n^{n - 1}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \sim n e$$
then :
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(k + 1)^k}{k^{k - 1}} \sim \sum_{k = 1}^n k e = e \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}$$
So ;
$$\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n \dfrac{(n + 1)^n}{n^{n - 1}}}{n^2} \sim e \frac{n (n + 1)}{2 n^2} \to \frac{e}{2}$$

Comment: Your answer suggests that from a asymptotic equivalence $a_n \sim b_n$ it follows that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sim  \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$ which is false in general.

Comment: It's true when the series diverges and non negative which is the case.

Comment: I know, it's called Stolz-Cesàro theorem, look at the other two answers. The point is that there's no mention of it in your proof.

Comment: I don't know why my answer is considered as not useful !!!